# Format String C++

Tags: c++

I have a pointer and I would like to convert the pointer address to a string and display the address in a message box. Is there a function similar to printf() that can format a string? This does not seem to work.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
    HINSTANCE prevInstance,
    LPSTR lpszArgument,
    int nFunsterStil)
{
  int x = 5;
  int* ptr = &x; 

  MessageBox(NULL, printf("%p", ptr), "Pointer", MB_OK);
  return 0;    
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use `sprintf` (or as someone else suggested, the more safe `snprintf`) to first print the pointer to a buffer or even better use a `stringstream` to put the pointer in a string.

```
stringstream tmp;
tmp << ptr;
MessageBox(NULL, tmp.str().c_str(), "Pointer", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out `std::ostringstream`:

```
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream oss;
int a(5);
std::string b("Hello!");

oss << "This is an example! " << a << ", so I will say " << b;

// use oss.str() to return a string!
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a conversion that Boost can do: `MessageBox(NULL, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(&x).c_str(), "Pointer", MB_OK);`

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf` is good, but `snprintf` is better

Comment: Or `sprintf` is bad, `snprintf` is less bad ;)